# Java getFloat troubles - decimals being truncated

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm querying a postgres database where I am storing some floats.  I see in postgres where inputs are successfully being stored with decimal values, but when I query postgres with Java and put them into textboxes via setText the decimals are being trimmed.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs;

rs = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \"tblSamples\" "
    + " WHERE \"fnName\" = '" + cmbFnName.getSelectedItem().toString() + "' LIMIT 1;");

while ( rs.next() ) {
        txtID.setText(rs.getString("ID"));
        //attempt 1: 
        txtXoffset.setText(String.format("%f", rs.getFloat("fnXoffset")));
        //attempt 2: 
        txtXoffset.setText(String.format("%0.000000000f", rs.getFloat("fnXoffset")));
        //attempt 3: 
        txtXoffset.setText(String.format("%d",(long)rs.getDouble("fnXoffset")));
                }
```

None of these things are working.  I can't tell if it's because of the "get" portion, the "set" portion, or because the string formatting isn't happening correctly.

To be clear, I do want to trim trailing zeroes, but that is less important than getting the decimals in to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format string is a `.` followed by the number of wanted digits followed by `f`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.12f", 1.0));
```

Just for completeness, note that for user-entered values, the database usually stores fixed point numbers that in Java are called BigDecimal and not floating point numbers.

Comment: Useful feedback, but the results are quite odd. I used `String.format("%.16f", rs.getFloat("fnXoffset"))` and the output for 1.02 became 1.0199999809265137.  Is this what you are talking about with BigDecimal?  Also, your response gave me some fresh eyes on this and I found that `String.format("%s", rs.getFloat("fnXoffset"))` gives me the desired results.

Comment: Fixed point and floating point are totally different kind of numbers. You format string `%s` maybe works as you want to because the field type is decimal and not float